# Regex pattern matching with sentence which has words starting with entered words

Tags: regex, python-3.x

suppose i have two words

```
words = ['create', 'mult']
```

and list

```
list = ['can we create malfunction channels in teams', 'i want to create multiple teams in microsoft teams']
```

i want to filter sentence in  **list** with word in **words** if full word matches or it contains word which start with word in **words**

```
desired output = ['i want to create multiple teams in microsoft teams']
```

here 1st sentence gets filtered as it has no words starting with mult although it has create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
import re

words = ['create', 'nn']

sentenses = ['can we create malfunction channels in teams', 'i want to create multiple teams in microsoft teams']
pattern = re.compile(''.join([r'\b{word}\w*\b.*'.format(word=word) for word in words]))
result = [s for s in sentenses if pattern.findall(s)]

print(result) # []

words = ['create', 'mult']
pattern = re.compile(''.join([r'\b{word}\w*\b.*'.format(word=word) for word in words]))
result = [s for s in sentenses if pattern.findall(s)]
print(result) # ['i want to create multiple teams in microsoft teams']
```

Comment: i dont want to match pattern if it exist in between word. It should always start with word from words

Comment: @AkshayKumbharkar than provide more examples in your question because it’s unclear for what are trying to achieve

Comment: @alex200v, i have words like [create, mult], n i should get sentence which contains this word as startletters or whole word not in between the word

Comment: I asked you to provide more examples at least 2-3 in addition with current one I can’t help you because I don’t understand what are trying to achieve

Comment: @alex200v words = ['how','un']    list = ['how to unlock', 'how to shunt']    ans = ['how to unlock']

Comment: Ok, provide an example where my solution gives you wrong answer

Comment: list = ['can we create malfunction channels in teams', 'i want to create multiple teams in microsoft teams']     words = ['create', 'nn']  i get ans = ['can we create malfunction channels in teams']    here i get ans as nn is between the word 'channel' but i should i get blank list as there is no word in sentence which begins 'nn'

Comment: @AkshayKumbharkar does it help?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a regex pattern for this. The only comparison needed is to test whether one string starts with another string: [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith).

You want to test:

1. for each sentence in `list` ...
2. where ANY word starts with one of the phrases in `words` ...
3. for ALL of the phrases in `words`.

Then

```
words = ['create', 'mult']
list = ['can we create malfunction channels in teams',
    'i want to create multiple teams in microsoft teams']

result = [sentence for sentence in list
    if all(
            any(
                word.startswith(phrase)
                    for word in sentence.split()
                )
            for phrase in words
        )]
```

leads to

```
['i want to create multiple teams in microsoft teams']
```

You can run it with different `words` to verify it's really working.